# ReferenceError: sendButton is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Hi this is my code for a basic programming class where we are building a real time web chat web app.

I get the below error when debugging on firefox:

```
ReferenceError: sendButton is not defined
```

Please see my whole code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Chat {BETA}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Google Web Font -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://techify.org"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>STARTS</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="progress.html">Progress</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="rtwc.html">CHAT {BETA}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>



    <script src = "http://nuigchat-nuigexplore.rhcloud.com/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {

            // create a websocket to the chat server
            var socket = io.connect ('ws://nuigchat-nuigexplore.rhcloud.com:8000/');
            // send button event handler
            var sendButton = document.getElementById("sendBtn");
            // handle for user name
            var userName = document.getElementById("uName");
            // message text box handler
            var messageText = document.getElementById("msgTxt");
            // clear button event handler
            var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearBtn");
            // main message window
            var messageWindow = document.getElementById("msgWindow");
            // send button "on click" code
            sendButton.onclick = function () {
                sendButton.onclick = function() {
                    sendMessage();
                };

            };
            // re usable function
            function sendMessage() {
                if (userName.value!="")
                {
                    console.log("userName is not null");
                    if(messageText.value=="") {
                        console.log("messageText is null");
                        alert("Please type in a message");
                    } 
                    else {
                        console.log("messageText is not null");
                        console.log("Calling sendButton.onclick function");
                        socket.emit('send', {message: messageText.value, username: userName.value});
                        messageText.value="";
                    };
                } 
                else {
                        console.log("userName is null");
                        alert("Please type in your name!");
                    };
                };
            // handle incoming messages. Append the username and message to the existing content in the div.
                socket.on('message', function (data) {
                    messageWindow.scrollTop = messageWindow.scrollHeight;
                    messageWindow.innerHTML += '<b>' + data.username + ':</b>' + data.message + '<br />';
                    if (data.username !=userName.value) {
                    Sound('/starts/Pop.wav');
                    }
                });
            msgTxt.onkeyup = function(event) {
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                    sendMessage();
                }
            }
            function Sound(soundURL) {
                document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
                    "<embed src='"+soundURL+"'hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
                };
        }
    </script>
    <span id="dummy"></span>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="page-header" align="center">
                <h2><br><small>NUIG Real Time Web Chat</small></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id = "banner" style = "background: #5399a6;
        width: 500px;
        height: 53px;
        margin: 0px 0px 10px 100px;
        border: solid 1px #BDBDBD;">
            <img src="/starts/img/logo.png" width = "176" height = "52">
        </div>

        <div id="msgWindow" style="width:500px;
        height:300px;
        margin: 1px 0px 10px 100px;
        border:solid 1px grey;
        background: #ffffff; 
        overflow-y:scroll;">
        </div>

        <div id="controls" style = "margin: 0px 0px 1px 100px;">
            Name: <input id ="uName" style = "width:128px;".><br>
            <br>
            <input id = "msgTxt" style = "width: 350px;">
            <input id = "sendBtn" type = "button" value = "send">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

so i am wondering what is causing the error?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon i am now having trouble to get the sound to play when message comes, i have changed the code above to represent our fix

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the variable `sendButton` when the windows `onLoad` event occurs.  But your definition of the click event is happening outside of the onLoad event function, so it doesn't exist and is undefined.  Move your click event definitions into the function for `onLoad`

Comment: i am now having trouble to get the sound to play when message comes, i have changed the code above to represent our fix

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the sendButton var inside the window.onload function. That means it's local to that function.
What you'd be better off doing if you're using them throughout the page in different functions is declaring the variable outside of the window.onload and then using them inside it. For example:

```
var sendButton, userName, variables etc;
window.onload = function() {
    sendButton = document.getElementByIf('sendBtn');
    // more variables
};
```

Then you can use them in other functions. As an aside, you'll need to bind the event handlers inside window.onload as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is fixed, great. Second, for the audio, I first paste the relevant code:

```
    function Sound(soundURL) {
            document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
                "<embed src='"+soundURL+"'hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
    };
} // window.onload end
</script>

<span id="dummy"></span>
```

It would be better to use this:

```
    var currSong = "";
    function Sound(newSong) {
        if (newSong != ""){
            if(currSong != "" ) {
                document.getElementById(currSong).pause();
            }           
            var newSongEl = document.getElementById(newSong);
            newSongEl.currentTime = 0;
            newSongEl.play();
            currSong = newSong;
        }
    }
} // window.onload end
</script>

<audio id="audio" src="/sounds/music.mp3" autostart="false"></audio>
```

<sup>JS Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927838/starting-and-stopping-audio-in-javascript)</sup>

Where `newSong` is the id of the element.

Hope this helps!